# Storing a PHP array as an object in an API

Tags: php, arrays, api

Am working on a custom project build using PHP Laravel. I have captured some inputs from a form and want to store them in an API. Basically the API accepts an array of objects. Am trying to store my inputs but it doesnt save all of them and only saves the first one.

**What the API requires**

```
[
    {
        "dependant_name": "Dependant 1 ",
        "relationship": "Spouse",
        "date_of_birth": "1999-02-26"    
    },
      {
        "dependant_name": "Dependant 2",
        "relationship": "Child",
        "date_of_birth": "2008-11-21"    
    },
    {
        "dependant_name": "Dependant 3",
        "relationship": "Child",
        "date_of_birth": "2015-10-17"    
    }
]
```

**My inputs  after collecting from the form**

```
$fn = [
  "fName1" => "Martoo",
  "fName2" => "dsjksdksd",
  "sName1" => "Njogu",
  "sName2" => "jkdsjsdk",
  "dob" => "07-04-2001",
  "dob1" => "06-04-2001",
  "relation1" => "Wife",
  "relation2" => "Son"
];
```

**My code to check if a key exists**

```
 //If fName exist create only one array collection to suit API
    if(array_key_exists("fName1" , $fn)){ 
        $a=[
            'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
            'relationship' => $fn['relation1'],
            'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob']
        ];
    }

    //If fName and fName2 exists create 2 array collections to suit API
    if(array_key_exists("fName1" , $fn) && array_key_exists("fName2" , $fn)){ 
        $a=[
            'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
            'relationship' => $fn['relation1'],
            'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob'],

            'dependant_name' => $fn['fName2'] . " " . $fn['sName2'],
            'relationship' => $fn['relation2'],
            'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob1']
        ];
    }

   dd($a);
```

After dd($a) I get only the 1st array collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change structure of `$a` as follows

```
if (array_key_exists("fName1", $fn)) {
    $a[] = [ // you were replacing $a every time here
        'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
        'relationship'   => $fn['relation1'],
        'date_of_birth'  => $fn['dob'],
    ];
}

//If fName and fName2 exists create 2 array collections to suit API
if (array_key_exists("fName1", $fn) && array_key_exists("fName2", $fn)) {
    $a[] = [ // you were replacing $a every time here
        'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
        'relationship'   => $fn['relation1'],
        'date_of_birth'  => $fn['dob'],

        'dependant_name' => $fn['fName2'] . " " . $fn['sName2'],
        'relationship'   => $fn['relation2'],
        'date_of_birth'  => $fn['dob1'],
    ];
}

dd($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array to store output. You can use below code.

```
$fn = [
  "fName1" => "Martoo",
  "fName2" => "dsjksdksd",
  "sName1" => "Njogu",
  "sName2" => "jkdsjsdk",
  "dob" => "07-04-2001",
  "dob1" => "06-04-2001",
  "relation1" => "Wife",
  "relation2" => "Son"
];
$a = array();
//If fName exist create only one array collection to suit API
if (array_key_exists("fName1", $fn)) {
  $a[] = array(
    'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
    'relationship' => $fn['relation1'],
    'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob']
  );
}

//If fName and fName2 exists create 2 array collections to suit API
if (array_key_exists("fName1", $fn) && array_key_exists("fName2", $fn)) {
  $a[] = array(
    'dependant_name' => $fn['fName1'] . " " . $fn['sName1'],
    'relationship' => $fn['relation1'],
    'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob']
  );

  $a[] = array('dependant_name' => $fn['fName2'] . " " . $fn['sName2'],
    'relationship' => $fn['relation2'],
    'date_of_birth' => $fn['dob1']
  );
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
```